# Design a frame for shelves in an alcove?

Tags: walls, framing, woodworking, shelving

My previous small studio apartment had a useful cupboard, as pictured -- the only storage space, used for:

- Clothes
- Empty suitcases
- Small boxes

[image]

Now I want a design for a similar one, to fit the new space.

[image]

The space:

- The alcove is 185 cm wide x 260 cm high (6 foot wide x 8 ½ foot high).
- The alcove is 60 cm deep

The walls:

- The rear wall is solid (another apartment beyond it)
- The right wall is an interior wall. I don't know what's inside it. There's an electrical socket and light switch on its kitchen side. The 7 cm hole drilled through it for the washing machine hose is rough (not lined) and looks like it's a solid white plaster or concrete (which I don't understand or know about).

  [image]
- Behind the left wall is presumably a duct which carries electricity or ventilation to all the floors. The building is a 4-storey apartment built near Paris France in the 1970s.

The design -- similar to the first photo, above:

- A central wall will divide the space into two halves, each 90 cm (3 feet) wide, which would be the lengths of the shelves -- or each half could be subdivided, to create 4 quarters (as shown in the first photo) -- or the whole alcove could be divided into three instead of two
- The shelves *must* have user-adjustable height -- this is my only firm requirement -- i.e. holes at intervals up the sides, into which insert or remove little shelf-support pegs, onto which to place the shelves
- Maximum weight on each shelf will be less than 15 kg (30 lb), less than 100 kg total (200 lb) on all shelves
- I'd prefer it to have doors, too -- maybe four hinged doors each about 45 cm wide -- otherwise maybe sliding doors, or a curtain
- It's fine if it looks like the previous one above i.e. wood and/or white, but I don't care much about the appearance or materials -- just as long as it's functional and well-made

The problems:

- There will be a slim washing machine (45 cm deep, 85 cm high, 60 cm wide) on the right

  - This requires up to 10 cm behind it for its pipes, so effectively 55 cm deep
  - There's an electrical socket for it, and a small hole at the bottom of the interior wall  for its hoses to run to the water pipes in the cabinet under the sink
  - To minimize noise I suppose it wants to sit directly on the floor and so the new framing cannot have a floor/base
- There's an existing baseboard along the bottom of the walls, 12 mm (half an inch) thick and floating a fingernail's width above the wooden flooring
- The "fuse box" is on the left-hand wall

  [image]
- There's a ventilation duct high on the left-hand wall -- I don't know why because I don't feel any air circulating through it.

Because of the "problems" listed above I suppose it cannot be prefabricated units, and must instead be made-to-measure.

In general:

- **What is a suitable design?**

In detail:

- **What supports the shelf-ends on the walls?**

  Can I have something like a "tonks strip" a.k.a. "bookcase strip" attached directly to the existing wall?

  Or should there be a new vertical "jamb" attached to the wall -- whose purpose would be, to support shelves, and perhaps support door-hinges too?

  I guess in theory the new vertical could be a wall, or, only a pair of wooden planks or metal poles at either corner?

  Cupboards usually have side walls (e.g. 60 cm wide and 260 cm high in this case) -- is this true for built-in cupboards too, instead of reusing the existing alcove walls, for some reason? So should I do that, but cut a 45 cm x 25 cm hole in this side-wall for the fuse-box to peek through, plus a 10 cm hole near the edge of the other wall for the washing-machine hose?
- **What keeps the vertical walls vertical?**

  Perhaps there are several options:

  - Affix its at top edge (to the ceiling of the room, or to a roof on the cupboard), and its bottom edge onto the floor
  - Have a base on the floor (to attach the bottom to the base instead of to the floor) on the left-hand side, even if nothing on the right-hand side because of the washing machine
  - Have a frame i.e. a plank or board at the top ("head") and bottom ("sill") at the front and back
  - One of the shelves could be fixed (and therefore help to brace the wall which it's attacked to), instead of movable -- i.e. the shelf immediately above the washing machine is at a well-known height
- **What about the baseboards?**

  Do the baseboards need to be removed? Or can the new vertical jambs co-exist with them?
- **What about the roof?**

  The ceiling is high. The previous one (the first one pictured) had a roof on top of which I stored empty suit-cases. I could do that again, if 260 cm is too high -- but it would be neater if instead they were invisible on a top shelf inside the cupboard.

  260 cm would be too high for a prefabricated sliding door, but not for meade-measure doors nor for a curtain.

  Is there anything else to consider, about the height?

  What about that ventilation louvre, would it be very wrong to put that inside the new cabinet -- i.e. should there be a roof below the bottom of the louvre, which would be 230 cm instead of 260 cm?
- **What about the backboard?**

  Correct me if I'm wrong, I assume a backboard is optional/cosmetic and maybe unwanted.

  A backboard could be used to affix the rear side of the interior vertical walls, but I assume these also need bracing at the front, and that however they're done at the front (i.e. using a horizontal frame/plank) can be done at the back as well, instead of supplying a whole new 260 cm x 185 cm backboard/wall.

Comment: Wall drilled through appears to be typical of the "gypsum block" which I gather is common in Europe. 100x50x10cm blocks (other thicknesses may be available.)

Comment: Hi Chris, you appear to have multiple questions including design ones. This site works beeter with one question per post. And design is off topic.

Comment: @RohitGupta I don't see "design is off-topic" stated in the Help or on Meta? And if by "design"you mean "aesthetic appearance" then I'd agree that's subjective; but when I say "a design" I mean "a plan for a feasible implementation (given the requirements and constraints)" which I'd think must be on-topic.

Answer (score 3):

"User adjustable"…

That means you've to either make provision yourself for being able to place shelves at varying heights, by fasting battens around three side of the alcove at as many heights as you think fit…

…or just go to Ikea & get some [Ivar shelving](https://www.ikea.com/gb/en/p/ivar-shelving-unit-pine-s69251345/). Fasten this through to the rear wall for absolute stability. [Use long, heavy screws through short lengths of copper pipe as stand-offs to account for the skirting.

Ivar is just happily 89cm wide, which will probably miss your skirting on the side walls. I have two junk rooms & my office/workroom fitted out just the same [though some is Hejne which is stronger, but the wrong size for you.]

You don't need to buy full 'kits', you can buy individual parts. You can also saw some down to get full ceiling height. They make simple metal straps you can screw to hold legs firm on top of each other.

[image]

This is actually the precursor to Hejne, which was heavier still, showing two pieces strapped together* & how copper pipe is used as stand-offs to clear uneven walls, skirting board etc [& an older fastening point, from before I doubled the height.]
Ivar has closer shelf-mount holes, every 30mm.

[image]

*<sup>One leg has twisted slightly over time [it's right next to the washing machine & has occasionally got damp], but they have been up nearly 30 years.</sup>

And I managed to find a bit of Ivar that wasn't too camera-shy - fastened back the same way.

[image]

I know we don't like direct product recommendations, but this one is a no-brainer for that space. ;)

Comment: Another good solution. Prettier than my laundry -room-special, might even be price competitive.

Comment: It's not *too* expensive - & I do like that you can actually saw it down to custom sizes. I've one piece that's 100cm at the top, but then just a column of 50cm underneath. Shoes one side, computer the other. Printer & display on top. The Hejne is actually a little easier to customise, fewer fiddly metal parts & neat cut corners to juggle.

Comment: Well, the question was basically, *what do I need to buy from IKEA to do something here*, +1. But really it should be the fridge and a dishwasher.... Should we tell the OP that **the enclosure requires three feet of working space in front of it**, or just let them go nuts?

Comment: @Mazura I don't understand your comment. Of course there is space in front of the enclosure. And the made-to-measure solution I tried to copy (in the first photo) wasn't from Ikea, and was complete with walls and a back and a roof,

Comment: @Tetsujin Thank you for posting. When I used Google to search for "Hejne" it returned other Sponsored results too including a metal rack solution (not from Ikea) which might be better -- because it's a closer fit, with shelf sizes up to 60 cm and height up 2500, and stronger, free-standing, with the uprights bolted to the shelves. That's user-adjustable with bolt-holes in the uprights every 4 cm, though not as easily. Anyway this is functional, and faster and cheaper than made-to-measure cabinetry! Before I do, I'll ask a local company about making and installing made-to-measure doors for it.

Answer (score 0):

My solution for a similar space in an apartment was to build a  backless shelving unit that fit the space, sizing it to brace against the side walls for stability. Mine was a quickie melamine build for mixed adjustable shelving and clothes-hanging space; this could be made much prettier by using real wood and adding a face frame or other trim.

Basically the same thing the "California closet" people sell, but doing some additional design and assembly work rather than paying the surcharge for their precut system. Though they offer better materials and a drawer option; I didn't bother and just used shelves. (Mostly adjustable, a few structural).

I'm sure a websearch for "built-in bookcase" will find designs of this sort, though I just threw mine together. ("Plans? What plans?") So I'm not going to do a full write-up here, just point this out as a good option if you want to minimize damage to the landlord's walls; it just needs one hole in the wall for a safety bracket at the top.

If the landlord is ok with your doing so, the easier solution is to mount a set of adjustable-shelf rails to the wall, snap in brackets at the heights where you want shelves, and toss boards on top of those brackets (as finished it unfinished as you like). I went with the more complicated approach mostly because I also wanted some additional clothes-hanging space.

Comment: I'd definitely do that [& have done in every alcove in the house] except the OP has 60cm depth. That's a lot for a rear-supported 'quick click' shelving system.

Comment: They don't have to use the full depth. If they want to, my semi-freestanding version was 18" deep. (Top sized to fit the gap, space divided to permit N uprights -- I left open space at each end for broom storage and similar talk things -- shelves sized to fit between the uprights mostly resting on shelf pegs since I built from predrilled melamine but a few fixed shelves to improve stability. Less than full wall height so I could swing it into place; extra space over top becomes another shelf. Notch the bottom back of uprights to fit over baseboards so it's flush to wall. Safety L-brace @top.)

Comment: `If the landlord is ok with your doing so` There is no landlord, I own this apartment for me occupy. `sizing it to brace against the side walls for stability` A sketch or photo might help me understand what you're writing.  A lot of my question is about bracing the interior vertical wall. `mount a set of adjustable-shelf rails to the wall` Maybe that was part of my question: whether a strip (aka adjustable shelving bracket) can be attached to a wall or whether it needs a jamb.